# PowerBI show month as number

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI I need a solution for how I can see/show the "Month" from a Date hierarchy as a number in any filter or visualization.

That's my simple date hierarchy with Year/Month/Day. I only use the month as I work with periods in my report.

[image: 1]

Now, if I use "Month" from the hierarchy it is shown by filters and visualizations as the name of the month.:

[image: 2]

I would like to see the months as a number. Also, it is important to use the "Month" from the hierarchy as many DAX use it for calculations (YTD, next, previous month total DAXs).

Could you please help?

Thanks,

András

Comment: One of the thumb rules of Power BI is to use flattened Date Table where you can assign the month numbers in a separate column and utilize information from there.

Comment: You don't need date hierarchy at all - DAX does not use it. You only need a proper date table with continuous dates.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 'switch' calc should do the job, something like this should work for you. This is helpful as some orgs work with fiscal years instead of calendar years, and the 1 doesn't always start on January.

```
> `MonthNo = SWITCH('Year - Month'[Month], 
>         "Jan", 1,
>         "Feb",2,
>         "Mar",3,
>         "Apr",4,
>         "May",5,
>         "Jun",6,
>         "Jul",7, 
>         "Aug",8,
>         "Sep",9,
>         "Oct",10,
>         "Nov",11,
>         "Dec",12
>                 )`
```

Comment: Thanks, you mean I should add that as an additional column? How, where to add the above? Otherwise, yes this is exactly the situation. We work with fiscal years starts at July 1, there is a half-year phasing. Due to that name of the month is misleading, but the number of the month (considering as periods in a fiscal year) would be fine in my reports.

Comment: Yep, go into the data view (left hand side of Power BI desktop), and then on the ribbon bar there's a 'New Column' button that you should be able to click and drop in that statement.